# Self-hosted WCF TCP connection error

Tags: wcf, tcp

I am new to WCF and stuck on a NET.TCP connection problem.

Here's the setup.

Server: Windows 8 Pro.

Self-hosted WCF Service, using NetTcpBinding with SecurityMode.None:

```
try
  {
    _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MouseTest));
    _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMouseTest), new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), 
          "net.tcp://localhost:" + MyNetwork.Default.Port.ToString() + "/MyWPFServiceHost");
    _serviceHost.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,5);
    _serviceHost.Open();
    AddMessage("net.tcp open");
  }
  catch (CommunicationException ce)
  {
    // MUST open visual studio as administrator!!!!! (Not this app, but actual VS2010.
    Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
    _serviceHost.Abort();
    AddMessage(ce.Message);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    AddMessage(ex.Message);
  }
```

Client machine (various types):

```
private void openTCPServiceButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  String endpointAddress = "net.tcp://XX.XXX.XX.XX:" + MyNetwork.Default.Port.ToString() + "/MyWPFServiceHost";

  if (channelFactory == null)
    channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMouseTest>(new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None),
      new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress));
  SendToListBox(channelFactory.Endpoint.Address.ToString());
  try
  {
    proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    proxy.StartRecording();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    AddMessageThreadSafe(ex.GetType().ToString() + ": " + ex.Message);
  }
}
```

The service is hosted  on my home machine, a Windows 8 box. When I connect from the same machine, all is well. From a different machine on the same LAN, all is well. From outside the LAN (on my office machine), I get:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8085/MyWPFServiceHost. The connection attempt
>   lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.1241124. TCP error code 10061: No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it.

Same error if I completely disable the Win8 firewall.

If I run a copy of the service on a  Windows Server 2008 machine at home, I can connect fine from anywhere, including over the internet.

Please, after 3 days of this I am getting nowhere. Please also remember that this is SELF-HOSTED and not IIS hosted. Many thanks for any insight or where to start looking. I have made sure that all the services that are normally mentioned with this 10061 error are turned on.

Comment: Have you checked `MyNetwork.Default.Port.ToString()` has same value(8085) on both the client and the service side?

Comment: And what do you mean by putting this "net.tcp://XX.XXX.XX.XX:" in your code?

Comment: Ports are the same number. And the XX's are just for my privacy here. As I said, the service works on a Server2008 machine, its just something about the Win8 box I can't figure out.

Comment: Are you able to ping to this IP? Do you have any other service working between these two machines?

Comment: No, I am not able to ping the IP address from outside. And to your 2nd Q - there are no services running between the two machines.

Comment: I can reach the machine externally just fine using TcpListener/TcpClient/NetworkStream, but I wanted to 'upgrade' to WCF and do a comparison. Just can't connect with WCF.

Comment: UPDATE: I have it working. I had to choose a different port, enable the inbound rules for that port, did the router forwarding, and restarted the machine. I have a range of ports 8085 to 8088, and only two of them work. I can see no difference in any other setup. Is it possible that some ports in this range are reserved or in use? Is there a way I can tell?

Comment: Do you mean on your router or your computer?.. You can open up you command console and do 'netstat /?'. There are optional parameters/arguments that you can pass to see listening ports and the associated, running processes. 

You could also download Sysinternal Suite, and run the Tcpview utility.

Comment: Changed the port on the service, added it to the firewall inbound and outbound rules, and set the port fowrding on the router. Only 2 ports work this way, 8083 ans 8086. I can't remember anything special about these ports, maybe something I did a while back. Seems that any new ports I try get the same error above. I can live with it but its annoying me not understanding. The ports I have tried are not in use according to netstat, before I try them.

Comment: Are you behind a NAT? 
May be this is something very specific to your Network's layout. WCF don't have any such port restrictions for sure. May be the other ports are being used by some other service.

Comment: I am not so familiar with this term - but the setup I am testing this on is a residential home network using the typical cheap linksys WRT51 router.

Comment: You can read about NAT here http://www.howstuffworks.com/nat.htm I think Wikipedia also got a good article on NAT.

Comment: @Dean Looks like this is solved. Could you write your solution in an answer and accept your own answer?